# Using Traefik Reverse Proxy to Redirect Local DNS Entry to Protected Domain

Tags: docker, traefik

I have a domain registered with cloudflare, and from my internal network, I want to be able to type something like `portainer.local` into my browser, and then have that be redirected to `portainer.mydomain.cc`. I've done this successfully with NGINX Proxy Manager in the past with no cert warnings, etc., but I just can't seem to get it to work with Traefik.

To start, I have local cname record that points `portainer.local` to `portainer.mydomain.cc`, and a dns entry that points `portainer.mydomain.cc` to the my Traefik reverse proxy container.

Here is my Portainer container compose file that shows the Traefik labels:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  portainer-ee:
    container_name: portainer
    image: 'portainer/portainer-ee:latest'
    restart: always
    network_mode: broker
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
      - '9443:9443'
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
      - '/mnt/docker/mapped/config/portainer:/data'
    labels:
      - 'traefik.enable=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=https'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.mydomain.cc`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer.middlewares=portainer-https-redirect'
      - 'traefik.http.middlewares.portainer-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.entrypoints=https'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.rule=Host(`portainer.mydomain.cc`)'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.tls=true'
      - 'traefik.http.routers.portainer-secure.service=portainer'
      - 'traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9443'
      - 'traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https'
      - 'traefik.docker.network=broker'
```

For completeness sake, here is my Traefik container with labels:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    traefik:
      image: traefik:latest
      container_name: traefik
      restart: always
      network_mode: broker
      security_opt:
        - no-new-privileges:true
      environment:
        - CF_API_EMAIL=myemailaddress@gmail.com
        - CF_DNS_API_TOKEN=mycloudflaretoken
      ports:
        - '80:80'
        - '443:443'
      volumes:
        - '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro'
        - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro'
        - '/mnt/docker/mapped/config/traefik/config/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro'
        - '/mnt/docker/mapped/config/traefik/config/acme.json:/acme.json'
        - '/mnt/docker/mapped/config/traefik/data:/data'
      labels:
        - 'traefik.enable=true'
        - 'traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http'
        - 'traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.mydomain.cc`)'
        - 'traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect'
        - 'traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https'
        - 'traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik.mydomain.cc`)'
        - 'traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth'
        - 'traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true'
        - 'traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=cloudflare'
        - 'traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].main=mydomain.cc'
        - 'traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].sans=*.mydomain.cc'
        - 'traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal'
        - 'traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=myusername:mypasswordhash'
        - 'traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https'
        - 'traefik.http.middlewares.sslheader.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https'
```

Here is my `traefik.yml` config:

```
api:
  dashboard: true
  debug: true
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: https
          scheme: https
  https:
    address: ":443"
serversTransport:
  insecureSkipVerify: true
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    directory: "/data/"
    watch: true
certificatesResolvers:
  cloudflare:
    acme:
      email: myemailaddress@gmail.com
      storage: acme.json
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: cloudflare
        resolvers:
          - "1.1.1.1:53"
          - "1.0.0.1:53"
```

Last but not least is the yml file I made in the `/data/` directory, referenced in the `traefik.yml` file:

```
http:
  middlewares:
    redirect-portainer-middleware:
      redirectRegex:
        permanent: true
        regex: "http://portainer.local/(.*)"
        replacement: "https://portainer.mydomain.cc/${1}"
  routers:
    redirect-portainer-router:
      rule: "Host(`portainer.local`)"
      entrypoints:
      - http
      middlewares: 
      - redirect-portainer-middleware
      tls:
        certresolver: "cloudflare"
      service: "noop@internal"
```

I admit I'm a little in over my head as I just started with Traefik yesterday, and that NGINX Proxy Manager had been relatively easy to configure in comparison to my attempt here. Using a wildcard cert from letsencrypt (obtained from cloudflare), all I had to do was make a redirection host and point it to my proxy host, and it always worked. Am I on the right track here, or am I way off base? Any help I can get would be appreciated.